# deploy a Java application with Apache Derby as a DBMS?

Tags: java, deployment, derby

I have developed a Java Application that connects with a database (insert, select ...) with Apache Derby as DBMS, this appication is running fine on NetBeans, but when I export it in a Jar, and I run it outside without NetBeans, I receive this error:

after running this command:

```
 java -jar jarre.jar
```

I get this list:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xka9.jpg]

I want my application to be portable, without starting NetBeans.
I know that I am missing something, but exactly what, is something I want someone to put light on?

Comment: Please paste the exceptions (including stack trace) as text and try to run the application with an English locale so that the messages are English and not French.

Comment: error when connecting to server localhost on port 1527 sent the message Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 40000

Comment: Is switching databases an option? Aaron's great answer below is why I abandoned Derby and discovered H2: http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby is an ex-IBM product and they are a bit fanatic about security (which can be good or bad). In your case, the Derby database uses the Security Manager API to make sure a lot of things are "safe". See the documentation how to [properly configure your security manager](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevcbabejdfj.html) **on the Derby Server**.

The second option is to disable the security; don't install a SecurityManager in your **client**.

I once spent roughly a week to set everything up correctly. This seems odd because Derby supplies example security files. The problem is that once you install a SM, it applies to *everything*

So you might need to change code in non-Derby parts, write more extensive policy files for those parts of the code and do a lot of ugly stuff that is scarcely documented. I didn't like it. For the most part, it felt like stabbing in the dark.

Disabling the security is often the preferred option unless your code was written with security in mind from the ground up (and all frameworks that you use, too).

Comment: solved ^ ^ I used H2 database engine it's very easy ^ ^ Thanks for ALL...  http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: Same here. H2 means much less maintenance but it does occasionally have severe bugs ... for about two weeks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the last exception printed (`java.net.SocketException`) and its stack trace it seems like the [Security Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) of your JVM doesn't allow the socket to be created.

Try setting an appropriate [SocketPermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#SocketPermission) for your application.